# What tense is in this message? What exactly does the message below translate as in English?

Tags: german-to-english, tense

Die letzte Szene hat immer wieder geprobt werden müssen

Comment: Translation requests are off-topic here. You may get away with it if you can explain a bit what you already researched and what you don't understand and why the dictionary did not help.

Comment: Why are they off topic? Who makes the topics? I am just asking a question. Ok what tense is in my message - are we allowed to answer that?

Comment: "The last scene had to be rehearsed again and again." But read the guidelines about pure translations. The sentence is overly complicated, IMO: "Die letzte Szene musste immer wieder geprobt werden" sounds better and simpler. Here, "werden" indicates passive, and not some kind of future tense.

Comment: @derSchotte: About what's off topic, there might be a discussion on meta.

Comment: Help yourself: https://www.deepl.com/translator

Comment: The community makes the topics. In practice, it is decided by voting on the (https://german.meta.stackexchange.com)[meta site].

Comment: This question is on-topic: *"What tense is in this message?"* But this is off-topic: *"What exactly does the message below translate as in English?"* Also not allowed: Asking two (or more) independent questions in one post.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple perfect tense, complicated by the additional presence of both passive and modal markers.

> Die letzte Szene hat immer wieder geprobt werden müssen

=

> The last scene has had to be rehearsed over and over
>   (i.e., they've had to rehearse the last scene over and over)

(Note that "müssen" looks like an infinitive, but is in fact a replacement form for the past participle which is used only in specific circumstances - this is one such circumstance.)

Comment: This is interesting. In translation it sounds like the 'passive voice' but isn't grammatically formed in any of the tenses of the passive. Anyway, to my German friends - do you agree that the sentence is an acceptable one? Meaning it does not have any grammar mistakes in it? (I don't think I will ever get the hang of German by the way!)

Comment: That sentence is grammatical and the preferred way to express that thought. Perfect, passive voice had been *Die Szene **ist** immer wieder geprobt **worden**.* *Geprobt* is in here because it's passive voice and *worden* is the past particple of *werden* as an auxiliary. If you mix in modals as *müssen*, *worden* becomes *werden* again, *ist* changes to *hat* (because *müssen* requires *haben*), and *müssen* itself is put into the **Ersatzinfinitiv** instead of its past participle.